# emacs text-scale-decrease and text-scale-increase showing only numeric mode increments

Tags: emacs, font-size

I am using emacs and want to change the current buffer font size using a keybinding.

Have been using the following keybindings

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-,") 'text-scale-decrease)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-.") 'text-scale-increase)
```

I have also used

```
M-x text-scale-decrease
M-x text-scale-increase
```

and

```
C-x C-+
C-x C--
```

But I am getting a numeric value change in the Mode Line (-1,-2,-3,...) and (1,2,3...), without seeing any height decrease or decrease.

Comment: Maybe specify your platform and how you are using Emacs (console or GUI). And check whether you see a difference if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file) - if you do, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: It doesn't work if you're using `emacs` in a terminal or if you're using a gui Emacs and some rare and odd font it can't figure out how to scale.

Comment: Figured out the problem originated from having the scale step set to `1.0`.

Comment: Please add that as an answer.